# How to position the collapse menu in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to position the collapse menu. I am currently using bootstrap 3. I wanted to position it 30px from top. I tried but after loading it menu bounces back to its default position. Here is my html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-1" aria-expanded="false">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">AX<span id="orange">IT</span></a>
     </div>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Css:

```
.navbar-default{
background-color: black;
background-image: none;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
min-height: 80px;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
line-height: 80px;
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.69) !important;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-brand{
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.69) !important;
}
.navbar-toggle{
     top: 15px;    
}

.navbar-collapse{
    top:30px !important;

}
}

.navbar-brand{
font-size: 27px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 80px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
color: white !important;
}

#orange{
color: orange;
font-weight: normal;
}
```

here is JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amanturate/m8L712kr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to your `.navbar-collapse`

```
.navbar-collapse{
  top:30px !important;
  position:relative;
}
```